# Cascading Sum operation

Tags: java, cascading

I am very new about Cascading. Now I know how to do the word count using Cascading. Next I want to do some Sum operation. For example I have the following input:

```
a b c 1000
c d e 2000
a s e 5000
```

I want to SUM the last field. If I simply select that field and do COUNT it will give me the output like:

```
1000 1
2000 1
5000 1
```

It is not what I want!! I want to SUM all these 3 numbers and give it a name which is called "duration" which looks like:

```
duration 8000
```

I can name this field which is called "duration" but I don't know how to SUM it itself and put a key work "duration" front when output into a file.

This is the code I tried:

```
... // get duration Field 
// determine the word counts
Pipe pipe = new Pipe("pipe", docPipe);
pipe = new GroupBy(pipe, new Fields("duration"));
pipe = new Every(pipe, Fields.ALL, new Count(), Fields.ALL);
```

But it gives me the wrong output which I have shown above.

Maybe I shouldn't use Count, but I tried SumBy it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't count, when you want to sum up?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the source code that's relevant to your problem!

Comment: What is `Pipe`, what `GrouBy`, `Every`, `Fields`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the sum over all values, i.e. you want just a single group, the "fields" parameter to `GroupBy` should be `Fields.NONE`. Also, since you're summing the duration field, you should make that the argument selector in `Every`. The following code does what you want:

```
pipe = new GroupBy(pipe, Fields.NONE);
pipe = new Every(pipe, new Fields("duration"), new Sum(), Fields.ALL);
```